# Getting a malloc error when not using printf()

Tags: c, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct lis
{
    int num;
    struct lis * next;
} list;
void  fun(list ** h, int nu) {
    *h = malloc(sizeof(list)*nu);
    list *p = *h;
    int i=1;
    list * nextx;
    while(i<=nu) {
        nextx = p + 1;
        p->num = i;
        p->next = nextx;
        //printf("%d\n", nextx);
        p += 1;
        i++;
    }
    p->next = NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    list * first = NULL;
    fun(&first,10);
    free(first);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm learning lists in c

whenever this code is run it gives an malloc error

if i comment out `printf("%d\n", nextx);` which shows next node it works fine.

what is happening?

Comment: Please post a complete example. Be sure to show all variable declarations and initializations. Also show the exact error message you get.

Comment: If adding/removing `printf()` statements changes whether you get an error, it's almost always a sign that you're causing undefined behavior somewhere in the program. UB doesn't always trigger an error, it just corrupts memory, and it then depends on what you do afterward whether you get an error.

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Ask yourself what `p` points to upon loop *exit*, and question what `p->next = NULL;` subsequently does.

Answer (score 5):

In the last run of the loop, your code do:

```
nextx = p+1; // points one past the last array' element
p->num = nu-1; // ok
p->next = p+1; // probably not what you wanted, but not a fault per se
p += 1; // This is the cause of your problem
i++; // out of the loop...
p->next = NULL; // dereference out of array pointer!
```

Quit the loop one step before and then set the last element correctly:

```
while (i<nu) {
   ...
}
p->next = NULL;
p->num = nu-1;
```